# pritunl VPN Server use domain name instead of IP Address in Client Profiles

Tags: openvpn

How can I set up the pritunl server so that in the client profiles it uses the domain name instead of the Server IP Address?

in ovpn file instead of  `remote x.x.x.x 12290 udp`
use  `remote mydomain.com 12290 udp`

Checked their documentation and did not find anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe based on this: https://forum.pritunl.com/t/route-public-domain-through-vpn/864 that pritunl does generally Not support routing to domain names.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/548036)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Public Address in the Host configurations:

https://docs.pritunl.com/docs/configuration-4